# Finding text and using its location in Marathon Testing Tool/JRuby

Tags: java, jruby, marathontesting

Using Marathon to test a java application, I have a handful of rows and I want to commit some operations on a specific row that has certain text in one of its fields.

How would I go about searching for it and then selecting it to use it in Marathon or JRuby?

For example, I want to find the text "HERE" in a row, right click that row, and click one of the options provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this.

1. You can fall back to `WebDriver` interfaces and use find_elements.

   ```
   table = get_component('oscarTable')
   cells = table.find_elements(:css, '.::all-cells[text="102 Dalmatians"]')
   cells.each { |c| puts c.text }
   ```
2. Use text property and access the cell directly

   ```
   cell = get_component('oscarTable', { :text => '102 Dalmatians' })
   puts cell.text
   ```

In (2) you can use `select` instead of `get_component` to set the value of the cell (if the cell is editable etc.)

Comment: How do I know what parameter to send into get_component? There are multiple tables on screen so I'm not quite sure how to differentiate. When I return all elements using :css, "*", it gives me "TrueClass: 0x42590234". Not that exact number, but that format.

Comment: Best is to record something using the table and use the name generated by Marathon.

Comment: That worked. With your first code, it did print the text as well as "#<TrueClass:0x2...>' 
I tried to just do rightclick(cells) and it threw a type error. 
How would I utilize the obtained element?